# insert into select vs bulk insert

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table A, about 400k rows one day, I want to write java program to back up old data to another table, there are two ways:

1. use jdbc to fetch data from table A, 500 rows one time for example, then concatenate sql like `insert into table B values(value1, value2...),(value1, value2...),...` then execute.
2. use `insert into table B select * from A where`, about 2~3 million rows.

As somebody said the second way is slower, but I am not sure, so which way is better? Must not crash database.

Comment: But, how would you get the data in first case ?

Comment: @Ravi, `select * from A where... limit 500`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st one is the realistic option but you dont have to do it by concatenating SQL. Java JDBC already has functions for sending inserts in batches. In a for loop you can keep performing inserts for one row at a time then when you reach your desired batch size call executeBatch() to post it in one big bulk insert.

The value that you'll have to play around with is how many to insert at at time or the batch size. That answer will depend on your hardware so just see what works. The larger the batch size the more units held in memory at anyone time. For really large databases doing this I have still crashed the program BUT NOT the database. It was only when I found the right batch size for my system did everything work out. For me 5000 was fine. But running it many many times for over a million rows the database was fine. But again this depends on the database as well. But you are on the correct path.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-batch-processing.htm